# MSI M2 - Multisource shipping?

Tags: magento2, shipping, msi

We are using MSI Multistock (multisource) and want to be able to ship from multiple sources in M2 in **one shipment**. In short it does the following

- sell items from multiple sources as shown in image
- when shipping apply multisource shipping, and deduct 1st as much as possible from source 1, then continue to source 2 (actual just like the column 'deduct' in the screenshot)

Currently we can only select 1 shipping source because it is a dropdown. We would rather like to assign multiple sources just like the `deduct from` column in the overview.

Amasty has something in their extension for MSI, the problem is that it adds a lot of other features as well. We only need multisource shipping.

**Question**: HOw could we add multisource shipping as a shipping algoritm that applies per default for all orders /w the logic of 1st deduct from prio 1 source, if not enough continue to next. And Ship all in 1 shipment.

[image: Current shipping situation]

[image: Multisource shipping]

Answer (score 0):

Magento Allow only one source assignment per shipment, in case of qty per source you can create multiple shipment. please try once.